# Oracle Indexing Join on Not Null

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

We are doing SQL Tuning/Indexing on Oracle Database 11g. Currently there is no index on CustomerTransaction ProductId, so we want to add one to help with Join tuning performance. However, DBA noticed 95% of the ProductIds in CustomerTransaction are Null.  Does Oracle have an option to index on not-null rows only ? What is alternative way to index, or should we apply the index in this 90% distribution/statistics scenario?

```
select ct.customerId, pr.ProductName
from dbo.CustomerTransaction ct
inner join dbo.Product pr 
    on ct.ProductId = pr.ProductId


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTransaction](
    [CustomerTransactionId] [int] NOT NULL, // this is the primary key
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
    [SalesDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
    ...
   )
```

**ProductId, Count Distribution**
etc sample list

```
NULL,34065306
2,127444
3,103996
5,96280
6,78247
366,66744
9,58251
4,48056
10,29841
155,27353
8,22143
1052,20885
16,18298
23204,17242
21,16413
26,15084
11,15061
23205,14161
168,14086
7,14022
738,13294
115,12385
13,12119
18,11844
23208,11610
```

Comment: You say that 95% of the data has `ProductId` as `null` in `CustomerTransaction`, but the table is declared with `not null` for this column... Oracle doesn't index rows with nulls in all indexed columns. So in your case index will definitely be useful

Comment: If you are running that query frequently on your live schema then you are missing the elephant in the room. And astentx is right that the value can't be null.

Comment: hi @astentx my bad, I just changed to not null

Comment: Now edited, but if you are concerned about the performance you should be focussing on the more obvious issue.

Comment: what is the obvious issue? @symcbean

Comment: You may also use list partitioning with `values(null)` and `values(default)`, which would be more reliable than index

Comment: Why are you running a query that is returning every row in the product of the 2 relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single column B-tree indexes, Oracle will only index the rows where the indexed column is not null.

5% of a table can sometimes still be slower to read by an index rather than a full table scan, it will depend on how those rows are spread out.

Comment: hi, we are adding a nonclustered index by the way, so how do I tell whether to apply index or not?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Comment: yes I am using Oracle, I left a distribution count sample above

Comment: Your pasted syntax is very much not Oracle, it is for SQL Server. There is no clustered or non-clustered index in Oracle, there are indexes and index organised tables. Your pasted results says nothing about how the rows are spread out. For best results, test creating the index in your test environment and seeing if it improves things. Note that you don’t have any other filters so you’re still expecting lots of results, if that’s not expected then you probably want to add some filters

Comment: apologize, I do come from a SQL server background and app developer, but using Oracle,  I wrote the DDL way I envisioned, since I don't have dba access to see DDL in Oracle